# ActionNotSupported error when a WCF Service is created at runtime

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding

I am trying to create a `WCF` service at runtime. My service interface is:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IInformationService : IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "Get", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
     UriTemplate = "Test",     RequestFormat  = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string Test();
}
```

I am serving my service as follows:

```
var httpEnumerator = ImplementedContracts.Values.GetEnumerator();
httpEnumerator.MoveNext();

var httpContractType = httpEnumerator.Current.ContractType;
var webBinding = new WebHttpBinding()
                 {
                   Security =
                   {
                     Mode = WebHttpSecurityMode.None
                   }
                 };

var httpEndpoint = AddServiceEndpoint(
  httpContractType, 
  webBinding, baseAddress+/Get"
);

httpEndpoint.Behaviors.Add(new CustomEndpointBehavior());
```

The ServiceHost is created by this method:

```
protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
{
  var host = new WcfServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses);

  if (host.Description.Behaviors.Contains(typeof(ServiceDebugBehavior)))
  {
    (host.Description.Behaviors[typeof(ServiceDebugBehavior)] as 
    ServiceDebugBehavior).IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true;
  }
  else
  {
    var debug = new ServiceDebugBehavior
                {
                  IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true
                };

    host.Description.Behaviors.Add(debug);
  }

  if (host.Description.Behaviors.Contains(typeof(ServiceMetadataBehavior)))
  {
    (host.Description.Behaviors[typeof(ServiceMetadataBehavior)] as ServiceMetadataBehavior).HttpGetEnabled = true;
    (host.Description.Behaviors[typeof(ServiceMetadataBehavior)] as ServiceMetadataBehavior).HttpsGetEnabled = true;
  }
  else
  {
    var smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior
              {
                HttpGetEnabled = true,
                HttpsGetEnabled = true
              };

    host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
  }

  host.AddServiceEndpoint(
    ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName,
    MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpsBinding(),
    "mex"
  );

  host.AddServiceEndpoint(
    ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName,
    MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(),
    "mex"
  );

  return host;
}
```

Service route creation:

```
var serviceRoute = new ServiceRoute(
  "wcf.service/" + service.Value.Name, 
  new WcfServiceHostFactory(), 
  service.Value
);

if (!RouteTable.Routes.Contains(serviceRoute))
{
    RouteTable.Routes.Add(serviceRoute);
}
```

When I try to access my service from a web browser using the address

`http://localhost/Werp.View/wcf.service/InformationService/Get/Test`

I obtain the following error:

```
<Fault xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/envelope/none">
  <Code>
    <Value>Sender</Value>
    <Subcode>
      <Value xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">
         a:ActionNotSupported
      </Value>
    </Subcode>
  </Code>

<Reason>
  <Text xml:lang="en-US">
    The message with Action '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a 
    ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of 
    either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) 
    or a binding/security mismatch between the  sender and the receiver. Check 
    that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same  binding 
    (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).
  </Text>
</Reason>
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My problem has been solved when I added WebHttpBehavior to endpoint

```
httpEndpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need specific WCF features or you have mandate to use WCF you should consider using different stack for REST based services. For example [ASP.NET web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) or [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/). It looks like a lot of work to do a simple REST call.

If you turn on service diagnostics this might help diagnosing the problem. You can see this [SO for detailed instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925697/debug-ef4-savechanges-in-wcf-service-hosted-by-iis/10926587#10926587)

You can also refer to this [SO: WCF - ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487791/wcf-contractfilter-mismatch-at-the-endpointdispatcher-exception) for some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I needed to add a HTTP header to the request called `SOAPAction`, where the value was set to the xmlns path to the service I was requesting.